# Consider one's priorities vs. prioritize one's needs

Tags: word-usage

In the context of the sentence:

> You need to carefully consider your priorities in order to choose the most suitable solution.

Can I replace "consider your priorities" with "prioritize your needs"?

Comment: to consider and to prioritize mean different things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can replace one phrase with the other - they mean different things.

"Consider your priorities" means to think about what things should take priority in your life. The inference is that you should place a priority on specific things and keep other things in secondary place. For example, if you had limited financial means, your priorities would likely be paying essential bills for housing, amenities etc, and luxuries/recreation in a secondary place. So, this phrase is an instruction to decide which things should *be* priorities, and which things should not.

"Prioritize your *needs*" is more specific. "Needs" are arguably the same thing as priorities - if you *need* something, it is essential, not a luxury. This would be more of an instruction to place the things that are already priorities in a *priority order*. For example, if you had to choose between paying your rent and paying your electricity bill with the last of your money, you might conclude you have to pay your rent first, because it might be better to be in the dark than be homeless!